# sumar celdas con while en PHP agrupadamente

Tags: php

Tengo una tabla dibujada en PHP con registros de un select en la base de datos, y la dibujo así

```
      if(!is_null($plantilla)) : 
        $curp_prof = ' ';
        $hrs_base = 0;
        $hrs_comp = 0;
        $hrs_int = 0;
        $hrs_conf = 0;
        $hrs_mes = 0;
        $sumHoras = 0;
      while($i = mysqli_fetch_array($plantilla)) :
        if($curp_prof != $i[0] || $hrs_base != $i[1] || $hrs_comp != $i[2] ||$hrs_int != $i[3] || $hrs_conf != $i[4] || $hrs_mes != $i[5]){
      ?>
          <tr>
            <td>
            <a onclick="javascript:return confirm('¿Seguro que desea modificar?, al realizar esta opcion tendra que volver a asignar horas y materias');" href="coordinador.php?f=Eliminar&curp=<?php echo $i[14]; ?>">
              <center><i class="fa fa-pencil-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></center>
            </a>
            </td>
            <td><?php echo $i[0]; ?></td>
            <td bgcolor="#37831D"><center><?php echo $i[1]; ?></center></td>
            <td bgcolor="#37831D"><center><?php echo $i[2]; ?></center></td>
            <td bgcolor="#37831D"><center><?php echo $i[3]; ?></center></td>
            <td bgcolor="#37831D"><center><?php echo $i[4]; ?></center></td>
            <td><center><?php echo $i[5]; ?></center></td>
      <?php 
        $curp_prof  = $i[0];
        $hrs_base   = $i[1];
        $hrs_comp   = $i[2];
        $hrs_int    = $i[3];
        $hrs_conf   = $i[4];
        $hrs_mes    = $i[5];

        }else{

      ?>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
      <?php 
        }
      ?>   
        <td><?php echo $i[6]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $i[7]; ?></td>
        <td><center><?php echo $i[8]; ?></center></td>
        <td><center><?php echo $i[9]; ?></center></td>
        <td bgcolor="#37831D"><center><?php echo $i[10]; ?></center></td>
        <td><center><?php echo $i[11]; ?></center></td>
        <td bgcolor="#37831D"><center><?php echo $i[12]; ?></center></td>
        <td bgcolor="#37831D"><?php echo $i[13]; ?></td>
      <?php 

      $sumHoras = $sumHoras + $i[13];
      ?>
        <td bgcolor="#37831D"><?php echo $sumHoras; ?></td>
        </tr>
      <?php
      endwhile;
      ?>
      <?php
      endif;
      ?>
```

Da como resultado esta tabla:

```
+-----------------------------------+----------+------------+------------+
| profesor $i[0];                   | materia  |   $i[13];  | $sumHoras  |
|                                   | $i[7];   | gran_total |       suma |
+-----------------------------------+----------+------------+------------+
| CRUZ CORONA ALEJANDRO             | 1        |      23.20 |      23.20 |
|                                   | 2        |      23.20 |      46.40 |
| GUILLÉN ALCÁNTARA ERNESTO         | 5        |      23.20 |      69.60 |
|                                   | 3        |      23.20 |      46.40 |
|                                   | 1        |      23.20 |      72.80 |
| MORALES ARREDONDO THANIA BERENICE | 6        |      23.20 |      96.00 |
|                                   | 7        |      23.20 |     119.20 |
|                                   | 8        |      23.20 |     142.40 |
|                                   | 1        |      23.20 |     165.60 |
| MORALES RESENDIZ JORGE            | 9        |      23.20 |     188.80 |
```

Y quiero sumar las celdas de total y que salgan en suma, o sea por cada profesor, porque en el while si suma pero todas y quiero que lo haga por cada profesor.
PARA QUE QUEDE ASI

```
+-----------------------------------+----------+------------+------------+
| profesor                          | materia  | gran_total |       suma |
+-----------------------------------+----------+------------+------------+
| CRUZ CORONA ALEJANDRO             | 1        |      23.20 |      23.20 |
|                                   | 2        |      23.20 |      46.40 |
| GUILLÉN ALCÁNTARA ERNESTO         | 5        |      23.20 |      23.20 |
|                                   | 3        |      23.20 |      46.40 |
|                                   | 1        |      23.20 |      69.60 |
```

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema es que `$sumHoras = $sumHoras + $i[13];` nunca vuelve a cero cuando cambias de profesor.

Tu codigo es bastante complejo de leer, pero en algun lado, cuando:

```
if($curp_prof != $i[0])
```

quiere decir que cambiaste de profesor, y por lo tanto en ese punto deberias hacer

```
$sumHoras = 0;
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias por tu respuesta, y si ese if es el que tengo dentro del while 
    "if($curp_prof != $i[0] || $hrs_base != $i[1] || $hrs_comp != $i[2] 
    ||$hrs_int != $i[3] || $hrs_conf != $i[4] || $hrs_mes != $i[5]){"
ahi se inicia $sumHoras = 0;